# How to create a custom analyzer in Pylucene 8.6.1?

Tags: python, search, lucene, full-text-search, pylucene

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012843/writing-a-custom-anaylzer-in-pylucene-inheritance-using-jcc), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13426157/delimitedpayloadfilter-in-pylucene) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432969/custom-tokenizer-for-pylucene-which-tokenizes-text-based-only-on-underscores-re?answertab=active#tab-top) but I'm not sure why they don't work for me.

I would normally use an analyzer like below.

```
import lucene
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.core import WhitespaceAnalyzer
from org.apache.lucene.index import IndexWriterConfig, IndexWriter
from org.apache.lucene.store import SimpleFSDirectory
from java.nio.file import Paths
from org.apache.lucene.document import Document, Field, TextField

index_path = "./index"

lucene.initVM()

analyzer =  WhitespaceAnalyzer()
config = IndexWriterConfig(analyzer)
store = SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get(index_path))
writer = IndexWriter(store, config)

doc = Document()
doc.add(Field("title", "The quick brown fox.",  TextField.TYPE_STORED))
writer.addDocument(doc)

writer.close()
store.close()
```

Instead of the `WhitespaceAnalyzer()` I would like to use `MyAnalyzer()` which should have `LowerCaseFilter` and `WhitespaceTokenizer`.

```
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.core import LowerCaseFilter, WhitespaceTokenizer
from org.apache.pylucene.analysis import PythonAnalyzer

class MyAnalyzer(PythonAnalyzer):
    def __init__(self):
        PythonAnalyzer.__init__(self)

    def createComponents(self, fieldName):
        # What do I write here?
```

Can you please help me write and use `MyAnalyzer()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [here](https://medium.com/@ekaterinamihailova/in-memory-search-and-autocomplete-with-lucene-8-5-f2df1bc71c36) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012843/writing-a-custom-anaylzer-in-pylucene-inheritance-using-jcc) that the below works.

```
from org.apache.lucene.analysis.core import LowerCaseFilter, WhitespaceTokenizer
from org.apache.pylucene.analysis import PythonAnalyzer
from org.apache.lucene.analysis import Analyzer

class MyAnalyzer(PythonAnalyzer):
    def __init__(self):
        PythonAnalyzer.__init__(self)

    def createComponents(self, fieldName):
        source = WhitespaceTokenizer()
        result = LowerCaseFilter(source)
        return Analyzer.TokenStreamComponents(source, result)
```

It would be great if someone can point me in the right direction to be able to find these answer correctly.